# Typescript export a custom hook with typing from index file

Tags: typescript

I have a strange case I need to resolve.
My index.ts has :

```
export const Request = <T>() => ({
    useHandler: useOneTimeGuaranteedRequestHandler,
    ...
});
```

My useOneTimeGuaranteedRequestHandler.ts is :

```
export const useOneTimeGuaranteedRequestHandler = <T>({}) => {
...
}
```

What I need to achieve is :

```
export const Request = <T>() => ({
    useHandler: useOneTimeGuaranteedRequestHandler<T>,
    ...
});
```

I need to somehow pass the T to my custom hook.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const useOneTimeGuaranteedRequestHandler = <
    T extends SGEnvStructure
>() => ({
    useOneTimeGuaranteedRequestHandler(): T {
       ...
    },
});
```

in index use:

```
    useHandler: useOneTimeGuaranteedRequestHandler<T>()
        .useOneTimeGuaranteedRequestHandler,
```